# Why do images appearing differently when posted on linkedin.com than when posted via the API?

Tags: linkedin-api

When I post a share via the linkedin.com website and then grab its attributes and share them again from the API, the picture doesn't appear the same way.

Here's an example, the bottom post was shared from the web interface and then the top post was shared from the API: 
[image: Screenshot of 2 LinkedIN posts with identical attributes. Top was posted via API, bottom was posted on linkedin.com]

The attributes for these posts are identical. Here are the JSON attributes for the post shared via LinkedIn.com:

```
"comment"=>"Test1",
"content"=>
{"description"=>"",
"eyebrow_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"shortened_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"submitted_image_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"submitted_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"thumbnail_url"=>
"https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=80&h=100&hash=83SZltJ4k6E4eW%2B%2B%2F4R86FIVsLU%3D&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimage-store.slidesharecdn.com%2F47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"title"=>"Screen Shot 2014-11-13 at 3.37.02 PM.png"},
```

And the attributes for the post shared via the REST API:

```
"comment"=>"Test1",
"content"=>
{"description"=>" ",
"eyebrow_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"shortened_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"submitted_image_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"submitted_url"=>
"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"thumbnail_url"=>
"https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=80&h=100&hash=83SZltJ4k6E4eW%2B%2B%2F4R86FIVsLU%3D&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimage-store.slidesharecdn.com%2F47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png",
"title"=>"Screen Shot 2014-11-13 at 3.37.02 PM.png"},
```

Here's the HTTP request used to create the post via the API:

```
HTTP POST (935.00ms) https://api.linkedin.com:443/v1/people/~/shares
Request body {"visibility":{"code":"anyone"},"comment":"Test1","content":{"description":"","submitted_image_url":"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png","submitted_url":"http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/47dc092f-2411-4490-b8f0-8f5e587d1857-large.png","title":"Screen Shot 2014-11-13 at 3.37.02 PM.png
"}}
```

Is this a bug in the API or a difference between how LinkedIN handles shares from the API vs the web interface? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The Share API calls are not currently processed through the same crawler interface that shares made via linkedin.com are subject too.

When sharing via API, it will only use the information that is directly provided as part of the API request.  Via the website, a crawler script attempts to analyze the target page automatically for the necessary information.